# Most efficient way to do select hierarchical query - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a database with a gazillion rows and 5 fields - `State` (A), `City` (B), `Category` (C), `Subcategory` (D), and `ID` (E).  I will hit it with a gazillion queries like `SELECT ID`, with `WHERE` clauses that can contain the following, connected with `AND`s:

```
A
A,B
A,C
A,B,C
A,C,D
A,B,C,D
C
C,D
```

In other words, it will only include B if it includes A, and only include D if it includes C, due to the nature of the hierarchy of the columns.  Each of these would return a list of IDs, which may be many rows.

Would the following technique be beneficial?

1. Create two tables, one (`X`) with a compound clustered index on
   `(A,B)`, and the other (`Y`) with a compound clustered index on
   `(C,D)`
2. Take the part of my query on `{A,B}` (if any) and hit that against
       `X`; take the part of my query against `{C,D}` (if any) and hit that
       against `Y`.
3. If I hit both tables (i.e. the query included both parts of `{A,B}`
       and `{C,D}`), then intersect both tables on `ID`.

Would this be more efficient than just doing the fully query against the entire table?  Should I also make a secondary non-clustered index for `ID` on `X` and `Y`?

Comment: Don't think you can outsmart the query optimiser by breaking into separate tables, breaking into special ordered processing of temp tables etc. Most of the time if you index the tables correctly (and that might included partitioned tables), everything just works under the covers and you don't need convoluted processes. Some times you need to make it complicated but try indexing correctly first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an index on `A,B,C,D`, then it will help with these queries:

```
A
A,B
A,B,C
A,B,C,D
```

It will somewhat help with these queries:

```
A,C
A,C,D
```

It will not help with these queries:

```
C
C,D
```

If you create a second index on `C,D`, it will help with these queries:

```
C
C,D
```

If you create a third index on `A,C,D`, it will help with these queries:

```
A
A,C
A,C,D
```

So, I would keep everything in one table and have three indexes on it. As for, which index to make a clustered, it's hard to say. I'll start with simple index on `ID`, which would be primary key as well.

---

Everything above assumes that your queries are using all these columns with  "equality" filter, like this:

```
WHERE A='ValueA' AND B='ValueB' and C='ValueC'
```

If some of the filters are not `=`, but `>` or `>=`, then indexes may be not so effective. It depends on actual filter expression.

Comment: Thanks! So it is okay to make non-clustered indices, even though I am returning many rows?  I had heard this was bad.

Comment: "Something is bad" is too broad. If you are concerned about performance, try several variants with your hardware and real sized data and compare. What **is** usually bad, is denormalizing your data without a clear understanding why you do it and what you are gaining for it. (like splitting a table into two if it is a single entity, or on the contrary, merging two tables into one if they are two entities). Of course, each extra index makes updates of the table slower, so you are trading `SELECT` speed for `UPDATE/INSERT` speed. You should measure the impact and decide whether it is acceptable.